# create function creates two record

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

this is my create function:

```html
    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        record = super(Shift, self).create(vals)
        flag = False
        if record.Date_range:
          do smth   


        return super(Shift, self).create(vals)
```

but when I try to create a record by clicking on save button, it creates two records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method, you have called super method twice that's lead to create two record.

Replace code from

```
return super(Shift, self).create(vals)
```

to

```
return record
```